# How to use windows authentification with php / symfony

Tags: php, windows, session, authentication

I work on a Symfony application intranet. 
I heard about the possibility of using the authentication window rather than having to log in using a conventional authentication window.

Could someone could give me 1 or 2 link addresses on the subject? I searched for myself but I can not find the right keywords. 
Is he is WSSE?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you running this application on an IIS server which is in an AD togheter with the windows computers of the users?

Comment: yes excactly, i use an IIS server with AD

Comment: Then you can set the access for the website in your IIS interface to "Domain users" or something like that. Afterwards you can check against the `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` variable in PHP which contains `domain\user` information. You don't even need to show any login dialogue.

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking to do! 
If the user is in the network, it has nothing to do it is automatically logged. 
If he opens an incognito window, it's like he was out of network and therefore an authentication window opens automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your PHP application on an IIS instance on a windows server which is in an AD togheter with the other computers which uses this application you can turn off access for the website in your IIS interface for "Anonymous" users.

Afterwards you can check against one of the `$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`/`$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` variables in PHP which contains `domain\user` information. You don't even need to show any login dialogue. So it's a SSO (single sign on) process then.

See the link below for more information about this:

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/enable-php-applications-to-make-application-level-access-control-decisions

Answer (score 0):

If what you call "identification window" is the small alert on which you must type id and pass rather than an HTML form, you just have to take a look in direction of htaccess and htpassword as this small windows is the result of a htacces protection.

See here (eg):
http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/auth-htpasswd.html

Best regards
Peter

Answer (score 0):

Further to TiMESPLiNTER's comment above

On our IIS setup (IIS 7.5) the relevant server variable is $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] so if it doesn't work at first try using phpinfo() to find the right variable for your site.

Comment: Thx for mentioning this. But this should be a comment to my answer.

Comment: Quite correct but you need 50 reputation points to comment on somebody else's answer and I am still to new for that.

Comment: Oh forgot about that. Sorry then... somehow a stupid rule... at least in this case here.