# Intranet authentication using windows session

Tags: windows, active-directory, symfony

I am trying to develop an intranet that will be able for only windows users in domain.
The user should open his windows session (Login/password), and then get into the intranet with IE Browser, at this moment, we will verify if this user can access to dashboard or not.
Am using Symfony 3 to develop the intranet, and I have an Active Directory to return all informations about users.
What suggestion can you give me to resolve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my blog, it should be helpful.

For reference, I had to spend a lot of time to get this working; so i suggest using the test LDAP server "ldap.forumsys.com" first. You may need to create a few Symfony3 projects to try and test it out.

Here is the link to my blog:
https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/symfony-ad-integration/

Another useful thing is always to check the log in `var/logs/dev.log` to debug problems.

Comment: Thanks @Alvin Bunk, for your reply. after reading your blog there nothing about Windows authentication.
My need is :
1- User log in his windows session,
2- User open the browser and access to the intranet URL
3- I'll proceed to verification using the windows session credentials to check if he's allowed to see the dashboard or not.

Comment: Can you confirm: do you want to make the "computer" that the user is using authenticate, or do you want the Symfony3 application authenticate against Active Directory? Your post is not very clear.

Comment: I want unique authentication (Windows session), when the symfony3 application is called, i have to check if the user logged in can access the dashboard.
Is it more clear for you?

Comment: So like I said in my post above, go through my blog. The last part of my blog has a section **Getting AD Authentication to Work**, and that's where you are authenticating the Windows session. It seems you haven't done much research before posting your question...

Comment: I readed your blog many times, it's clear.
In my case, i have an application without login/password page authentication. The only way to access to the application is to be authenticated correctly to Windows session. 
My questions, is how can i get the username of the Windows session ? And then, I should check if this user is in the authorized group or not.

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this??? For example: take a look [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25527782/how-to-use-windows-authentification-with-php-symfony), maybe that might help you in some way?